# How to set same alignment for these two text

Tags: flutter, dart

**How do I make the second text align with the first text. Excerpt of the code is below**

```
                            Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20, left: 10),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    document.data()['Product Title'],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(height: 10,),
                                Container(
                                  child: Text(
                                    document.data()['Product Price'],
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Palette.mainColor,
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
```

**This is how it is at the moment**

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set the column crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start

Answer (score 2):

Set CrossAxisAlignment property to Column Widget.

Your Column Widget Should be like this after applying this property.

```
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start
                          children: [
                            Container(
                              child: Text(
                                document.data()['Product Title'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            Container(
                              child: Text(
                                document.data()['Product Price'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ), 
                          ],
                        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Add alignment property to your container.

```
 alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
```

**Edit:**

Ok, I got the problem. @M.M.Hasibuzzaman is right. You need to add `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`. The correct solution with full code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
    
      body: Row(
        
        children: [
          Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                  width: 80,
                  height: 80,
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  child: Image.network(
                    'https://cdn.friendlystock.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/2-loud-speaker-cartoon-clipart.jpg',
                  )),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "Loud Speaker",

                    // textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Text(
                    "GHS6758",
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red, //Palette.mainColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]